# Selenium Grid - Is it a paid Tool?

Tags: selenium, grid

Is Selenium Grid ( Server or Client ) a paid tool?

*I have surfed for this information and I didn't get much information on this.*

Answer (score 2):

Selenium grid is free, and you can find out more information on how to setup, and the project in general here:

- http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/get_started.html
- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 2):

From their [license page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/license.jsp)

> All Selenium projects are licensed under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

So no, it is not a paid-for tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is free and open source.

http://code.google.com/selenium

Please look at the documentation then come back with a particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to execute on the same Browser Type on the same Machine. This is not supported by Selenium Grid. Hence i took a different route and made the below changes.

- Make multiple folder copy with the execution jar along with the essentials like testng.xml, config files, IE driver.....
- Write a wrapper and trigger these execution jar one by one. It should work upto 5 IE11 browser on 4GB RAM machine.

This way we are able to run multiple tests on the same browser on the same machine cutting the usage of 3rd party tools like Sauce Labs, Browserstack at some extend...